# checkGroupInput return name of input choice (use named list in plot)

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, morris.js

I am using `checkboxGroupInput()` from the Shiny/ShinyDashboard-package to let users (de-)select elements of a plot (`MorrisJS`). The selection is passed from a named list as the *choices*-Argument to a function updating a data.frame (adding and removing elements).

However, `input$NameOfTheCheckboxGroup` returns only a vector with the selected choices, but not the label/name of the member in the list it takes as input. This means I can only name elements with the value  that I assigned to a choice.

Is there any way to improve that, so `input$NameOfTheCheckboxGroup` also returns the label/name? So far I have tried replacing the "y"-Argument in the plot to return the label of the list member, but this cannot work, as  the plot cannot find the data columns.

Replaced this:

```
y = colnames(de_solar)[2:NCOL(de_solar)]
```

With:

```
y = names(list1[match(colnames(df)[2:NCOL(df)],list1)])
```

Renaming the list members is unfortunately not an option.

[UI]

```
checkboxGroupInput("check_de_solar", label = h3("Label"), 
                                   choices = list("Option1" = 2097,
                                                  "Option2" = 409,
                                                  "Option3" = 410,
                                                  "Option4" = 411,
                                                  "Option5" = 412,
                                                  "Option6" = 2106,
                                                  "Option7" = 2107,
                                                  "Option8" = 2108,
                                                  "Option9" = 2109, 
                                                  "Option10" = 731),
                                                  selected = 2097)
```

[SERVER]

```
  output$de_solar <- renderChart2({

    de_solar <<- checkbox_call(df_data,"de_solar",input$check_de_solar)
    grph2 <- mPlot(x = "Date", y = colnames(de_solar)[2:NCOL(de_solar)], data = de_solar, type = "Line")

  })
```

To further illustrate, the current data.frame *de_solar* and list *choices* look like this:

```
 de_solar = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:50,10,rep=TRUE)))
choices = list("Option1" = 2097,
             "Option2" = 409,
             "Option3" = 410,
             "Option4" = 411,
             "Option5" = 412,
             "Option6" = 2106,
             "Option7" = 2107,
             "Option8" = 2108,
             "Option9" = 2109, 
             "Option10" = 731)
 names(de_solar) <- choices
```

This gives me this output:
[image: What I have]

But I want the same input to be:
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I apologize for not having selected your answer before. Your solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to improve that, so `input$NameOfTheCheckboxGroup` also returns the label/name?

Not really. Label information is not a part of the generated request so unless you want to implement a custom client-side logic it is not an option. As long as values are unique it shouldn't be a problem though. You can simply match values and extract names for example like this:

```
names(choices[choices %in% input$check_de_solar])
```

where choices is a list of **character** values:

```
list("Option1" = "2097", "Option2" = "409", ..., "Option10" = "731")
```